# Setting HoloViews backend in JupyterLab startup script

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh, jupyter-lab, holoviews

I'm trying to set up my JupyterLab environment so that HoloViews loads automatically using the bokeh backend. I've put the following code in my start.py file in the .ipython/profile_default/startup/ directory:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

opts.defaults(
    opts.Curve(aspect='square'),
    opts.Image(colorbar=True, toolbar='above', width=400, aspect='equal')
)
```

The startup script runs without errors and I can access HoloViews functions in my JupyterLab environment. However, when I try to plot anything (an xarray object for example) using hv.Image() or hv.Curve() I just get a blank output. If I then insert a cell in the JupyterLab notebook and execute hv.extension('bokeh') the plots start showing up when I rerun the plotting commands. They continue to work even if I restart the kernel.

This appears to be an issue specific to the bokeh backend, because if I change the backend to matplotlib (with appropriate modifications to the opts commands), all the plots show up from the start.

Anyone know what's going on here? It would be nice to be able to fully initialize HoloViews with bokeh from the JupyterLab start script.

Comment: What versions of bokeh and holoviews are you using?

Comment: Bokeh v2.4.0 and HoloViews v1.14.6 installed within an Anaconda3 environment